# SQL Server - Querying a XML Document for List of IDs

Tags: sql-server, xpath, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

What is the correct way to pull the list of IDs from this document as ints?

```
    declare @d xml
    set @d = '<doc><id>1</id><id>2</id></doc>'

    select Data.Col.value('/text()', 'Int')
      from @d.nodes('/doc/id')
        as Data(Col)
```

Using the method above I get a error
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.value() always requires a positional reference to identify the node you want.

```
declare @d xml
set @d = '<doc><id>1</id><id>2</id></doc>'

select Data.Col.value('.[1]', 'Int')
  from @d.nodes('/doc/id')
    as Data(Col)
```

Comment: After your post, I tried the same with one small change

select Data.Col.value('.[text()]', 'Int')

And it also works. Which is more correct? I am going after the text value of the node, not the 1st child of the node right? Thanks

Comment: As noted, both work well; however, I think that enclosing the text() statement in the predicate is doing an existence check, and returning the value of the first node, whereas the hardcoded 1 provides a specific reference point.  In this example, the nodes() method has already split the XML to the point that there is only 1 node per row, so the [1] and [text()] both point to the same location.